# $L_{\infty}$ not separable: Find nested subsets of $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ with positive finite Lebesgue measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

I'm trying to show that for any positive, finitely (Lebesgue) measured set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ the space of functions $L_{\infty}(\Omega)$ is not separable.

I have the argument down for $\mathcal{l}_{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ using characteristic functions $\chi_J$ of arbitrary subsets  $J \subset \mathbb{N}$. The analog in $L_{\infty}$ requests me to construct a nested sequence of subsets $\Omega_k \subset \Omega$ where each $\Omega_{k-1} \setminus \Omega_{k} $ is nonempty and has positive finite measure.

My intuition wants to find an interior point $x \in \Omega$ and use $\Omega_k = B_{1/k}(x) \cap \Omega$ and be done with it but $\Omega = \Big( \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \Big) \cap [0,1]$ is a counterexample of the existence of such $x$.

Help/hints/solutions to my problem(s)?

Comment: The space is separable if $\Omega$ is a finite set - do you mean that $\Omega$ is a set with positive Lebesgue-measure? In this case you think way too complicated. Just note that $\Omega$ can't be finite and you can embed $l_\infty(\mathbb{N})$ into $L_\infty(\Omega)$.

Comment: @Dominik: For that embedding you need a disjoint sequence of measurable subsets of $\Omega$ with positive measure, though, so essentially the same as the poster is asking.

Comment: @LukasGeyer You're right, I forgot about nullsets.

Comment: Hint: If $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure and $B_r$ denotes the ball of radius $r$ centered at the origin (open or closed does not matter), then $f(r)=\lambda(\Omega \cap B_r)$ is continuous, $f(0)=0$, and $f(r) \to \lambda(\Omega)$ as $r\to\infty$.

Comment: @LukasGeyer this was my thought too but I think that I need $\lambda(\Omega_k) <\lambda(\Omega_{k-1})$ so that the characteristic functions defined on consecutive $\Omega_k$ are finite distance apart?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the map $g: r \mapsto \lambda(B_r(0) \cap \Omega)$ is a continuous, nondecreasing map. Simply choose $r_i \in g^{-1}\left(\frac{\lambda(\Omega)}{i}\right)$ and $\Omega_i = B_{r_i}(0) \cap \Omega$.

Comment: But don't I need the map $g$ to be strictly increasing so that $\lambda(\Omega_k) < \lambda(\Omega_{k-1})$? See comment above.

Comment: I've actually chosen the wrong $r_i$, since I though you wanted an increasing sequence of sets. I've fixed it now. Note that by definition $\lambda(\omega_i) = \frac{\lambda(\Omega)}{i}$ is a strictly decreasing sequence. It doesn't matter whether $g$ is strictly increasing or just nondecreasing.